# php cron jobs not running after moving to php 7.2

Tags: php, cron

We have previously cron jobs on apacher server php version 5.6, now we have moved to php 7.2 , cron jobs are not being run , giving this error.

```
Session path "/var/www/sessions" is not writable for PHP!
```

We have not used session in any cron jobs.

May anyone let me know what kind of  issue is this?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is written in the error message. Any further answer would require guessing, since there is effectively no information on what you are actually doing. As a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, extract a [mcve] from your setup. If you haven't found the error yourself by then, you can use the info for asking here. Until then, delete that question though.

Comment: The issue is related to the `session_path` setting in `/etc/php.ini` - you should either set it to `/tmp` or change the user under which the cron-job is being run to be the user who owns `/var/www/sessions`. It is also possible that this folder does not currently exist - so creating it may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found issue for this it was path issue, cron jobs were not including up file above directory

```
include(../config.php); // this file was not including
```

so I found solution and changed the path to this

```
include("/var/www/html/config.php");
```

now all cron jobs are working fine